# Constrain the drag of rectangular ROI (Matlab)

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I have a simple program which replaces a selected region of one image with the corresponding region in another image. I am trying to use `imrect()` in conjunction with `makeConstrainToRectFcn` to select a rectangular ROI which cannot be extended beyond the boundaries of the image.

However, when I run the code, the ROI can initially be drawn to include the areas outside the image frame. This leads to the error: `Index exceeds matrix dimensions`.

Is there any way that the rectangle cannot be drawn outside the image from the outset? Alternatively, is it possible to ensure that the operation does not execute unless the rectangle is constrained within the axes limits?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

My code:

```
% Sample images:
X=imread('office_1.jpg');
Y=imread('office_5.jpg');

figure, imshow(X)
h = imrect;
api = iptgetapi(h);
fcn = makeConstrainToRectFcn('imrect',get(gca,'XLim'),...
   get(gca,'YLim'));
api.setPositionConstraintFcn(fcn);

wait(h);
rect = getPosition(h);
x1 =rect(1);
x2 = x1 + rect(3);
y1 =rect(2);
y2 = y1 + rect(4);

Z = X; % Initialize
Z(y1:y2, x1:x2, :) = Y(y1:y2, x1:x2, :);

imshow(Z)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
% Sample images:
X = imread('office_1.jpg');
Y = imread('office_5.jpg');

% Show image X:
figure, imshow(X);

% Define the ROI constraint:
h = imrect();
h.setPositionConstraintFcn(@(p) roi_constraint(p,size(X)));

% Wait for the ROI to be confirmed:
roi = round(wait(h));
x1 = roi(1);
x2 = x1 + roi(3);
y1 = roi(2);
y2 = y1 + roi(4);

% Create the final image Z and display it:
Z = X;
Z(y1:y2,x1:x2,:) = Y(y1:y2,x1:x2,:);
imshow(Z);

% Auxiliary function for ROI constraint:
function p_adj = roi_constraint(p,img_size)
    p_adj(1) = max([1 p(1)]);
    p_adj(2) = max([1 p(2)]);
    p_adj(3) = min([(img_size(2) - 1) p(3)]);
    p_adj(4) = min([(img_size(1) - 1) p(4)]);
end
```

The script has been tested under `Matlab 2017a` and works as expected. As you can see, the main difference is the way the size constraint is being handled: in your case, it wasn't properly applied before `wait` was hit, thus returning an invalid rectangle. Also, in order to avoid a wrong offsetting, the `round` function has been applied to the rectangle.

Comment: I'm sorry, I fixed my answer and now the code should properly handle also those cases.